# JScript runtime error with empty XML data

Tags: xml, javascript

I have a script that creates an html table and appends data from an xml file to the table cells. In one case, the xml data is empty i.e. `<event_title> </event_title>`, so there is only a space. This causes a JScript runtime error "Object required" in IE8. I've tried lots of non-printing characters instead, no joy. Here's the offending line, but I don't think that should matter, I really just need to discover how to create an "object" here that won't break the script.

```
var eventTitle = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("event_title")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `event_title` only contains text (no nested elements), you could try replacing

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName("event_title")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

with:

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName("event_title")[j].text
```

That's assuming you're using MSXML to parse the XML file ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762687%28VS.85%29.aspx)).  `.text` will return an empty string if there's no text (or just whitespace).

Comment: Yes, this works with all XML parsers I've tried. Thanks, Cheran!